# I want to remove null string from an array

Tags: php, arrays

var_dump($myarray);

This is my array output,I tried array_filter then i got all null values.pls help.I want to get 'Federal Bank (India) - Banking','Federal Bank (India) - Banking' from this array,how can i remove null from this.

```
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    string 'Federal Bank (India) - Banking' (length=30)
    null
    null
    null
    string 'Federal Bank (India) - Banking' (length=30)
    null
null
null
```

I tried array_filer($myarray,'strlen') also,but i did not get it.

Comment: Show your actual array...

Comment: Federal Bank (India) - Banking Federal Bank (India) - Banking

Comment: i cant echo it in a table

Comment: how i can remove this

Comment: Do one thing, Use `print_r()` instead of `var_dump()`. And copy result in your question...

Comment: print_r o/p is:Federal Bank (India) - Banking Federal Bank (India) - Banking

Comment: Try with array_values

Comment: have your problem solved?  are you satisfied with print_r()?

Comment: i tried array_filter,but it didnt work

Comment: when i echo this array table data is empty,other 2 nonempty strings are getting,i dont want this null string

Comment: where you are getting your array?can you show the actual array . add some more code

Answer (score 3):

Try `array_filter()`

```
$a = [null,'h',null,'g'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_filter($a ,function($a){
        if($a !== null)
            return $a;
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `array_unique(array)` removes duplicate entries, then remove single `null`

Try;

```
$array = array_unique($array);
if(($key = array_search("null", $array)) !== false) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use `array_filter()` See more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Code :

```
$new_Array=array_filter($old_Array);
print_r($new_Array);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. i assumed your array as given below. try to alter your code as required this may help you. let me know the result

```
<?php
$arr=array("null","null","Federal Bank (India) - Banking","null","null","Federal Bank (India) - Banking");
$str=implode(' ',$arr);
echo $str."<br>";
echo$new_str=str_replace("null","",$str);// replace all null and your expected output
?>
```